# Inconsistent results from du command

Tags: disk-usage

I'm trying to track down the biggest disk users on a disk that is getting full. I usually use the du command for this, but this time I'm getting strange inconsistent results from it that I don't understand.

I have already identified a user that is supposedly using 78GB of space:

```
# cd /home/userx
# du -sxk .
78066324    .
```

But when run du again on all the files to identify which files are the biggest, I get very different results:

```
# du -sxk * | sort -n
.
.
.
76240   RPMS
80828   save.oldcomputer
108536  docs
114472  rpmbuild
304652  chef-repo
```

i.e. the top five directories take up just over 500MB, and if you added up the whole lot including all the little tiny ones, it would still be less than 1GB. So where did the other 77Gb go?

Comment: Try something like `du -sxk .[a-zA-Z0-9]* | sort -n`

Comment: `-k` option means `--block-size=1K`, so 78066324K is about 76236M and about 74G. Sorting in reverse order could be done with `-r` option (if you want to get biggest first).

Comment: use `-h` (`--human-readable`) rather than `-k` to get sizes with K,M,G suffixes.

Answer (score 7):

Most probably hidden files. `*` doesn't include hidden files on expanding, so `du` won't report on them.

Try `du -axkd1 . | sort -n`

Comment: Of course! That was it exactly. I don't how I missed that. :) The version of du on the RHEL5 box doesn't have the -d or -1 flags, but running

    "du -axk . | sort -n"

showed about 60GB of old junk in ~/.local. Thanks!

Comment: `-1` is not a separate flag. The flag is `-d1`  for depth, which can also be substituted with `--max-depth=1`. So, you can also use `du -axk --max-depth=1 .` if your man page shows that.

Comment: @Stephan, if the file is unlinked, how would `du` encounter it to appear in a report?