Inconsistent results from du on an encrypted system
I am getting confusing results from du on an encrypted system. I used sudo everywhere in case there are any inaccessible files, but that did not help. I am using Linux Mint 21.3. I cannot tell if my home directory is 41 or 81GB.
sudo du -sh /*
includes this line
81G /home
sudo du -sh /home/*
41G /home/peter
sudo ls -la /home
shows only directories .ecrypts and peter
sudo du -sh /home/.ecrypts/
41G /home/.ecrypts/
sudo ls -R /home/.ecryptfs/
shows empty directory peter only.
How can .ecrypts be 41GB when it is empty? Is there some obscure feature of the encryption that means I have 41GB  of usable data as well as 40GB of encrypted?
I read on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303091/321108 that du doesn't include hidden files on expanding, so du won't report on them.
cd
du -sh .
still 41G
Thanks to @terdon for the leading questions in a comment. A naive mistake to forget to look for hidden directories in a hidden directory.
sudo du -sh /home/.ecryptfs/peter/.Private/
41G
Mystery solved!

You already had the reason, you just didn't realize it was the problem:

I read on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303091/321108 that du doesn't include hidden files on expanding, so du won't report on them.

That isn't about du, it is about how * works. You were running du /home/* which means "run du on the result of expanding the glob /home/*". And the * doesn't match on hidden files by default:
$ ls -al
total 44
drwxr-xr-x   2 terdon terdon  4096 Jul 15 15:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 203 terdon terdon 36864 Jul 14 20:32 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon     0 Jul 15 15:44 file
-rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon     0 Jul 15 15:44 .hidden_file

$ ls -l *
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Jul 15 15:44 file

See how the * doesn't match any of the dotfiles? That's exactly what you ran into when you ran du /home/* instead of du /home/. The * was expanded only to the list of non-hidden files and directories, but you had the hidden /home/.ecryptfs directory which was ignored. On the other hand, it is picked up by sudo du -sh /* because /* expands to the list of non-hidden files and directories directly under / and that includes /home, so everything in /home was counted.
Unless you explicitly want to limit results to only non-hidden files and directories, never use du /path/to/* and instead always use du /path/to/ (or /path/to).
